# I'm getting error The method setPromptText(String) is undefined for the type TextField

Tags: java, javafx

So I am can't seem to find anything on why eclipse wouldn't recognize the "setPromptText" function. It is asking me if I want to create method setPromptText:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class TextField extends Application {

    TextField tf;
    Label response;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        myStage.setTitle("Demonstrate a textfield");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10,10);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 230, 140);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        response = new Label("Enter Name: ");
        Button btnGetText = new Button("Get Name");
        tf = new TextField();

        tf.setPromptText("Enter a name.");

    }


}
```

Comment: I don't recommend using `.*` in your imports

Comment: don't use custom class names that are already used in core fx - you will confuse yourself and your co-workers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either change the name of your Class,

Or you can specify the package in the `new Textfield()` declaration.

E.G change the related line to this:

```
tf = new javafx.scene.control.TextField();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your class name is also TextField.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class TextField extends Application {

    javafx.scene.control.TextField tf;
    Label response;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    public void start(Stage myStage) {
        myStage.setTitle("Demonstrate a textfield");
        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10,10);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 230, 140);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        response = new Label("Enter Name: ");
        Button btnGetText = new Button("Get Name");
        tf = new javafx.scene.control.TextField();

        tf.setPromptText("Enter a name.");

    }
}
```

this code works